# How to know if a class is being set to a value

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I have made a little program that basically does this:

```
class Prop(object):
    def __init__(self, name, val):
        self.Name = name;
        self.Value = val;

class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self, prop):
        self._props = [prop];

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name != "_props":
            f = None;

            for p in self._props:
                if p.Name == name:
                    f = p;

            return f;
        else:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name);

cl = Prop("Name", "foo");
o = Obj(cl);

print(o.Name.Value); # by changing "f = p;" to "f = p[1]", I would simply do o.Name instead of o.Name.Value
```

This would return the name of the object, with no problems.

The problem comes when I want to set the value, but witheout actually doing .Value

The reason why I want to achieve that are many, such as making it simpler to edit objects, etc.

So, if I did something like

```
o.Name = "boo";
```

I wouldn't be able to, since I would have to do something like

```
o.Name.Value = "boo";
```

Even if I changed this piece

```
            for p in self._props:
                if p.Name == name:
                    f = p;
```

to something like

```
            for p in self._props:
                if p.Name == name:
                    f = p.Value;
```

I still wouldn't be able to do things like

```
o.Name = "";
```

Is there any **underscore** (double _) function I can use for this? Or is there any solution?

If so, how would I implement it to this system?

Comment: Python isn't C/C++, so you don't need to end statements with a `;`. In English, what _is_ your code basically doing—and what doesn't it do that you would like? I ask because this seems like it might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `__setattr__`:

```
class Obj(object):
    ...

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name != "_props":
            for p in self._props:
                if p.Name == name:
                    p.Value = value
        else:
            object.__setattr__(self, name, value)            

cl = Prop("Name", "foo");
o = Obj(cl);
print(o.Name.Value); # foo
o.Name = "boo"
print(o.Name.Value); # boo
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways for you to do this.

1) Define this relationship on the `__init__` method of `Obj`:

```
class Obj(object):

    def __init__(self, prop):
        self._props = [prop]
        self.Name = prop.Name
```

2) Create a method called `Name` for `Obj` using a property decorator. This allows you to access the return value of a method as if it were a property:

```
class Obj(object):

    @property
    def Name(self): 
        return self._props[0].Name
```

3) Turn `Obj` into a subclass of `Prop`:

```
class Obj(Prop):

    def __init__(self, prop, name, val):
        self._props = [prop];
        super().__init__(name, val)
```

Number 3) is probably the best way to work with such an interaction between classes without losing your sanity, but it also means that the `prop` argument is probably useless (or at least confusing in this case), and probably means that you'll need to change the most code (where this logic is affected).